# Why is young Ned Stark blonde?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why is young Eddard Stark from season 6 blonde? I thought in the *Game of Thrones* universe most Starks have black hair, particularly Ned has black hair mentioned in the books.

When I saw a young blonde dude (Robert Aramayo) characterized as Ned Stark I was confused.

Comment: We could make a long list of things in the TV series that do not match the books.  But let's not.

Comment: Can we please stop misusing books tag in show only questions? And Ned's hair in books is just dark (Which can be brown), not black.

Comment: Arya and Jon take after Eddard as per books, And both of them have brown hair, which means Eddard had brown hair, not black

Comment: And hair color can change while one grows up. A lot.

Comment: @Annatar Indeed. Many kids with light hair have their hair darken naturally as they grow up

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Young Ned Stark's hair colour matches old Ned Stark. You're making far too much of this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](https://ewedit.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/ned-stark.jpg?w=1200))</sub>